# Can I pass binary messages using crossbar.io

Tags: crossbar, wamp-protocol

So I want to transfer sound bytes over a websocket from a phone to a server. However according to http://crossbar.io/docs/Features crossbar seems to only implement json and msgpack. Can I stil transfer binary messages over crossbar using some other way? 
Also multiple crossbar clients ([for eg](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/jcelliott/turnpike.v2#Serialization) )seems to only provide json and webpack as de/serialization formats. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

WAMP is primarily intended for transmission of messages, not large (binary) payloads. For small chunks you can encode the audio so that it can be part of a regular WAMP payload. For an example of this for a webcam image, see the Tessel camera example - https://github.com/crossbario/crossbarexamples/tree/master/iotcookbook/device/tessel/camera. This works fine in principle, though there is, of course, the encoding/decoding overhead.